# Laravel 5 macros with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, macros

The situation - i wont make macros for Form, that include html and javascript.
According to the https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/tips/50-loading-form-macros i made provider and include the macros file

```
    Form::macro('multiple_select', function($name, $list = array(), $selected = null, $options = array())
{
    $select =  Form::select($name, $list, $selected, $options);
    $button = '<button type="button" class="btn button_add_multi_item">
            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-plus"></i>
        </button>';
    $select = $select . $button;
    $select .= '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . @asset('assets/js/macros/multiple_select.js') . '"></script>';
    return $select;

});
```

This element include select and +  element. By clicking on this element there should generate hidden input and span with selected option from the select. This is done by javascript in multiple_select.js file. The problem is - that jquery library file included in layout at the bottom of the page, and i got the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

If i wrote in main layout  -

```
        @yield('macros_scripts')
</body>
```

And in macros file

```
$select .= '@section("macros_scripts")<script type="text/javascript" src="' . @asset('assets/js/macros/multiple_select.js') . '"></script>@endsection';
    return $select;
```

then php generate string

```
@section("macros_scripts")@endsection
```

It doesn't handled by the blade template engine. 
So only 1 thing i can do - it's include jquery in the top of layout. But i beleave that there is other, correct way to include js in macros. Any tips, helps?

Comment: and it would be nice to include this script 1 time

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646562/how-do-i-use-includes-in-a-laravel-blade-macro
the solution